# Where is ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.Tasks.Utils.JSON documentation?

Tags: arcgis-server, wpf, silverlight

I'm using the WPF assemblies from the freely downloadable [ESRI WPF/Silverlight 2.0 SDK](http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/silverlight/index.html).

As I type in a "using" statement in visual studio, I can use intellisense to expand out into:

```
using ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.Tasks.Utils.JSON;
```

However, I don't see any documentation for it, nor does anything show up in the object browser.

Does anyone know where I can find more out about this?

Answer (score 5):

All the classes in this namespace (JsonWriter, ArcGISJsonWriter and ArcGISJsonReader) are **internal** to the ESRI.ArcGIS.Client assembly, so I suspect you won't be able to find any documentation.

It is a bummer, though, because these classes do all sort of useful conversion between ESRI's WPF types (geometries, geoprocessing parameters etc.) and JSON.

You can view the classes and their methods via Reflector, as I did. The IL is not obfuscated, but be careful not to violate ESRI's licence which I guess does not allow reverse engineering.